# Can I use Pandas Dataframe.assign(...) with a variable name

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote this bit of code so I can **group** any Pandas DataFrame and get the group size and a sample row of the dataframe as a quick result.

It works great, with one problem:
The **name** of the new column/index "Size" is **fixed**, because the `.assign( ... )` command doesn't take variables. So if my DataFrame has a column named "Size" it is lost.

My plan is to check, if a column named "Size" exists and if it does,
use a different name for the index. Can I use the `assign` command with
a **variable** for the field name instead of a **fixed text**?

I'd like to avoid a hacky solution like multiple renaming of columns.

```
import pandas as pd
try:
    from pandas.api.extensions import register_dataframe_accessor
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('Pandas 0.24 or better needed')

@register_dataframe_accessor("cgrp")
class CustomGrouper:
    """Extra methods for dataframes."""

    def __init__(self, df):
        self._df = df

    def group_sample(self, by, subset=None):
        result = (self._df.groupby(by).apply(lambda x: x.sample(1).assign(Size = len(x)))).set_index('Size').sort_index(ascending=False)
        return result
```

I can call this like this

```
df.cgrp.group_sample(by=['column1', ... ])
```

And get a result with an index "Size"

Comment: what stopping you from creating a function and use it in the apply?

Comment: @G.Anderson - yes, that's what I'm looking for, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to use dictionary unpacking. Instead of hard coding a name in the `assign` function:

```
.assign(Size = len(x))
```

You can use dictionary unpacking to specify a variable name:

```
.assign(**{col_name: len(x)})
```

I took some liberty to modify your `group_sample` function with 2 features: allow the user to specify a custom name and choose from a default list if they don't:

```
def group_sample(self, by, subset=None, col_name=None):
    _col_name = None

    if col_name is not None:
        # If a user specify a column name, use it
        # Raise error if the column already exists
        if col_name in self._df.columns:
            raise ValueError(f"Dataframe already has column '{col_name}'")
        else:
            _col_name = col_name
    else:
        # Choose from a list of default names
        _col_name = next((name for name in ['Size', 'Size_', 'Size__'] if name not in self._df.columns), None)

        if _col_name is None:
            raise ValueError('Cannot determine a default name for the size column. Please specify one manually')

    result = (self._df.groupby(by).apply(lambda x: x.sample(1).assign(**{_col_name: len(x)}))).set_index(_col_name).sort_index(ascending=False)
    return result
```

Usage:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5, (3, 2)), columns=['A','B'])
df1.cgrp.group_sample(by=['A'])     # the column name is Size

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5, (3, 2)), columns=['A','Size'])
df2.cgrp.group_sample(by=['A'])     # the column name is Size_

df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5, (3, 2)), columns=['A','B'])
df3.cgrp.group_sample(by=['A'], col_name='B')  # error, B already exists

df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5, (3, 2)), columns=['A','B'])
df4.cgrp.group_sample(by=['A'], col_name='MySize')  # custom column name
```